# How can I find out what causes this to always display, and remove it?

Tags: terminal, zsh

Every time I open my terminal, this greets me first:

```
Usage: prompt <options>
Options:
    -c              Show currently selected theme and parameters
    -l              List currently available prompt themes
    -p [<themes>]   Preview given themes (defaults to all)
    -h [<theme>]    Display help (for given theme)
    -s <theme>      Set and save theme
    <theme>         Switch to new theme immediately (changes not saved)

Use prompt -h <theme> for help on specific themes.
```

I've tried running through it more than once, but it keeps cropping back up.

As far as I have been able to tell, it's something left over from the Spaceship Prompt or Powerlevel10k, but I am not sure how to confirm whether it is or not, and ultimately how to remove it. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe an incorrect command somewhere that makes it display the help. Look at your `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: @lolesque Thanks, I'll give it a shot

Comment: @lolesque I removed some old Spaceship code and that seems to have fixed it. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it as the answer. Thanks